# Crear Instalador de un proyecto en laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp

Tengo un proyecto realizado en laravel, estoy usando xampp con servidor local.
Me gustaria saber como poner en produccion ese proyecto, osea pasar unicamente la carpeta public como se hace al subir a un servidor en la nube, sin exponer todo el codigo.
Si copio toda la carpeta de mi proyecto en otra computadora funciona perfecto, pero mi proyecto queda expuesto en la carpeta de htdocs de xampp..

Comment: Si pasas únicamente la carpeta public tu proyecto no va a andar, pues las funcionalidades que dependen de vendor estarán inexistentes

Comment: Claro, pero justamente estoy buscando la forma de no pasar todas las vistas y js, ya que si alguien elimina algo de ahi o modifica el sistema se romperia.

Comment: Entonces no estás considerando la protección física y lógica de la pc que actuará como servidor, no puedes esperar quitar partes del framework y que algo no falle

Comment: Claro, en un sistema, si alguien _borra_ o _mueve_, las cosas dejan de funcionar, por eso quienes administran servidores web, servidores de bases de datos, incluso terminales, son técnicos, con conocimientos suficientes para no romper las cosas.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dicen uds, y es justamente lo que estoy preguntando.
No se, si un cliente me pide un sistema que no va a estar alojado en la nube, tengo que instalar un servidor local y alli poner todo mi proyecto, pero alguien con un poco de conocimiento, podria entrar la carpeta del proyecto y modificar cosas, y es lo que intento evitar.
por Ejemplo desarrollando con delphi se crea un .exe donde contiene toda la informacion.

Comment: envia las carpetas del proyecto a otro path y modificas el index.php de public

Comment: @JJV entonces lo que pides es compilar el sistema...

Comment: si algo asi.. no se como explicar bien. el tema es que no quede expuesto el sistema a modificaciones que pueda alterar el funcionamiento, no voy por el tema de seguridad como el hackeo y esas cosas.. seria crea un ejecutable como los programas de escritorio..